# How do I get the correct list of numbers when querying mysql that has columns MIN and MAX?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a table in mysql that has on it columns for a Minimum number and a maximum number.

```
| ID | MinNumber | MaxNumber |
| 1  | 2         | 4         |
| 2  | 3         | 7         |
| 3  | 10        | 12        |
```

I want to get a list of numbers that is included in all ranges.

So the list should look like: `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12` Notice that 8 and 9 are missing because they are not within a range on the table.

Is there an easy way to get this range?

If it helps, I am trying to do this using PHP.

EDIT:
This needs to run optimally. The real table has over 200,000 rows in it and the ranges can be hundreds apart. Any way to cut down on the processing time for this would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would query the database for all rows. Then have a while loop run untill there are no rows. Inside that while loop run a simple for statement like so:
for ($i = MinNumber; $i < MaxNumber; $i++) {

Then just simply push to an array and print out the array after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you are mysqli to fetch
try this

```
    $array=[];
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $query)){
       $array=array_merge($array,range($row['min'],$row['max']));


    }

    asort($array);
    print_r($array);
```

Comment: Is there a way to initially cut down on the query? Any way to exclude rows that are already included or duplicates?